# Best way to power Raspberry PI 3 via GPIO

Tags: gpio, power-supply

I need to made device controlled with 3 Raspberry PI connected in cluster and want to made power supply via GPIO.

Do I need made 3V3 and 5V supply or just 5V on GPIO2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pins and GPIO are not the same thing.

**You can not power the Pi via the GPIO.**

You can power via certain pins on the expansion header.

Pin 2 and pin 4 are 5V pins.

You should only supply power via a 5V pin.

**DO NOT try to provide power via the 3V3 pins or any GPIO.**

Comment: See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)
for some more detail and Foundation recommendations.

Comment: Thank you guys. Realy i messup GPIO with regular pins. This help me a lot!